# Clarification for derivatives under a change of variables

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, field-theory, differentiation, calculus

In Special Relativity and Classical Field Theory by Susskind, he  says that we can imagine a function of $(x+ct)$, then he says that we can consider its derivatives and easily see that $$\frac{\partial F(x+ct)}{\partial t} = c\frac{\partial F(x+ct)}{\partial x}$$ If I think of examples, I can understand why this relation is true, however, I am unsure how to prove it. Could someone provide a hint/some insight to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x,t) = f(x + ct)$, then the chain rule gives
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial (x+ct)}\frac{\partial (x+ct)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial (x+ct)}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial (x+ct)}\frac{\partial (x+ct)}{\partial t} = c\frac{\partial f}{\partial (x+ct)}
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\end{align}